# Como Crear la clase Pilas en Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Me estoy recién inicializando en C-Sharp. Y tengo problemas al crear la clase pila en visual Studio, debo crear tres pilas, volcar los contenido de la pila1 a la pila auxiliar para que quede en la pila2 ordenada de la misma manera.
he llegado hasta aqui, pero no se como seguir, luego debo crear su form.

```
 class clsPila
   {
    int PilaA;
    int PilaB;
    int PilaC;
    int i;


    public void CrearPilas()
    {
        Stack PilaA = new Stack();
        PilaA.Push();
        i = PilaA.Pop();
        i = PilaA.Count;

        Stack PilaC = new Stack();
        PilaC.Push();
        i = PilaC.Pop();
        i = PilaC.Count;

        Stack PilaB = new Stack();
        PilaB.Push();
        i = PilaB.Pop();
        i = PilaB.Count;
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Ordenemos la pregunta.. es c# o c++?? son dos cosas muy distintas!!! y visual studio que tiene que ver aca?Todo ese codigo no hace nada.. que tiene que hacer???

Answer (score 0):

Estás redefiniendo PilaA, PilaB y PilaC. Es correcto que crees los miembros de tu clase al inicio de esta, pero no los debes de crear usando "int", debes modificarlo por Stack. Además no debes usar new si no vas a usar delete en el destructor de tu clase.

En principio usando:

```
Stack PilaA;
Stack PilaB;
Stack PilaC;
```

Y eliminando las líneas que crean la pila de nuevo debe funcionar. En el caso de que sigas deseando usar esa misma estructura te aconsejo reemplazar las primeras líneas por Stack *PilaA... Con el asterisco. De cualquier forma no puedes realizar una redefinición.

Como comentario: cuando haces un push a cualquier pila debes de pasarle como parámetro el valor que deseas introducir.

Más adelante y tras leer la documentación se recomienda especificar el tipo en el template de Stack, pasando a usar Stack si va a ser una pila de enteros.

Por favor, siempre programe en inglés, hará que sus programas sean mejor recibidos.